# QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to run the below Hibernate query, but I'm getting:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list [FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=r,role=com.efixlab.model.RestaurantRecommendedMenuItem.restaurant,tableName=RESTAURANT,tableAlias=restaurant1_,origin=RESTAURANT_RECOMMENDED_MENU_ITEM restaurant0_,columns={restaurant0_.RESTAURANT_ID ,className=com.efixlab.model.Restaurant}}]
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.1.Final.jar:5.4.1.Final]

```
SELECT mm
FROM RestaurantRecommendedMenuItem o
    LEFT JOIN FETCH o.restaurant r
    LEFT JOIN FETCH o.masterMenuItem mmi
    LEFT JOIN FETCH mmi.masterMenuCategory mc  
    LEFT JOIN FETCH mc.masterMenu mm
WHERE r.restaurantId = :restaurantId
    AND mm.masterMenuId IN
        (SELECT DISTINCT m.masterMenuId
         FROM MasterMenu m
         WHERE m.restaurant.restaurantId = :restaurantId)
```

Comment: as the exception says, you need to select `r` (the owner) and not `mm`. 
so you either select the `RestaurantRecommendedMenuItem` and then navigate (in Java) to the `masterMenu` or change the query

Comment: when tried with SQL, I'm getting the list

Comment: Hibernate is not exactly SQL. Here the exception is thrown before the execution of the query.

Comment: @boycod3 Are you using `Pagination`?

Answer (score -1):

Fetch is used to populate lazy load field in object, it has no use here. Just remove all FETCH keywords from your query and it will (probably) work.